# How to bind my tab to tabContent using AngularJS approach with DevExpress dx-tabs

Tags: angularjs, devexpress

I have created dx-tabs that are dynamically loaded in the view using custom directives.  I am able to output the tabs but I cannot figure out how to bind the cooresponding tab-pane with the tab.  I am thinking inside of my ji-Tabset directive in the addTab function I need to somehow create a variable that will loop through my scope.tabs array and then for each integer I need to create an instance of that variable.  Then inside of my ji-tab directive I need to push both the text and the content to the scope.tabs array.  Any thoughts?

**Directive 1 - Ji-Tabset**

```
module FormTest {
    angular
        .module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
        .directive('jiTabset', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                scope: {},
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    var tabs = $scope.tabs = [];

                    $scope.select = function (args) {
                        var tab = args.itemData;
                        angular.forEach(tabs, function (tab) {
                            tab.selected = false;
                        });
                        tab.selected = true;
                    };

                    $scope.tabSettings = {
                        bindingOptions: { items: "tabs" },
                        onItemClick: $scope.select
                    }

                    this.addTab = function (tab) {
                        tabs.push(tab);
                    };
                },
                templateUrl: "FormTest/views/ji-Tabset.html",
            };
        });
}
```

**Directive 2 - Ji-Tab**

```
module FormTest {
        angular
            .module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
            .directive('jiTab', function () {
                return {
                    require: '^jiTabset',
                    restrict: 'E',
                    transclude: true,
                    scope: {},
                    templateUrl: 'FormTest/views/ji-Tab.html',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
                        scope.text = attrs.tabName;
                        tabsCtrl.addTab(scope);
                    }
                };
            });
}
```

**Ji-Tabset templateUrl**

```
<div dx-tabs='tabSettings'></div><div ng-transclude></div>
```

**Ji-Tab templateUrl**

```
<div ng-show="selected" ng-transclude></div>
```

**Main view**

```
<ji-tabset name="Tabs" label="testing">
    <ji-tab tab-name="General">
        <ji-button label="Button 1"></ji-button>
    </ji-tab>
    <ji-tab tab-name="Stats"></ji-tab>
    <ji-tab tab-name="Stuff"></ji-tab>
    <ji-tab tab-name="Other"></ji-tab>
    <ji-tab tab-name="More stuff"></ji-tab>
</ji-tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever runs into this, I was able to figure out the solution.

I had to make a few changes in my directives and use DevExpress' onItemClick event handler itemData.  I had to add a view for ji-tab directive and transclude everything inside of it.  And also loop through my tabs array with angular.foreach.  I have updated the original post with the correct solution.